# Inserir dados no SQlite

Tags: javascript, sqlite, login

Estou aprendendo a utilizar o SQlite, porém não estou conseguindo inserir os dados.
Vamos lá, estou criando um simples espaço para o usuário digitar seu nome e senha e um botão para enviar os dados no SQlite. Meu html está abaixo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Banco de Dados Local</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="SQlite.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form class="login-box" onsubmit="save()">
            <h1>Login</h1>
            
            <div class="textbox">
                <i class="fa fa-user" ariahidden="true"></i>
                <input type="text" id="user" placeholder="Username" name="" value=""><br>
            </div>
            <div class="textbox">
                <i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <input type="password" id="senha" placeholder="Password" name="" value=""><br>
            </div>
            
            <input class="btn-2" type="submit" value="Register">
        </form>        
    </body>
</html>
```

Com esse html e com CSS, obtemos o resultado abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E no meu javascript estou criando uma tabela e inserindo dados, dessa maneira:

```js
var db = openDatabase("Meubanco", "2.0", "Mybase", 4048);
db.transaction(function(criar){
    criar.executeSql("CREATE TABLE users (ID PRIMARY KEY, nome TEXT, senha TEXT)");
});

function save(){
    var user = document.getElementById('user').value;
    var senha = document.getElementById('senha').value;
    db.transaction(function(armazenar){
        armazenar.executeSql('INSERT INTO users (user,senha) VALUES (?,?)',[user,senha]);
    });
}
```

Porém não está funcionando, olhei algumas fontes e não consigo encontrar erro. A tabela fica sempre vazia, assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém pode me ajudar, pfv?!!

Comment: Se você quiser continuar usando a lib do SQLite, basta fazer uma Query de busca, assim tu vai conseguir ver seus dados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo, é que você não está usando o WebSQL, apesar dela usar o SQLite por baixo dos panos, o WebSQL é uma API  integrada do HTML, pelo que vi, tu adicionou uma lib do SQLite, para usar o WebSQL você não precisa dela, basta estar com uma versão compatível do navegador.

Se você retirar do HTML o import do script do SQLite, provavelmente já irá funcionar.

Você consegue verificar a compatibilidade usando Javascript.

```
If(window.openDatabase){
     //implementação
 }
```